# How to get the accurate font size(height) in pdf

Tags: parsing, pdf, fonts, itext

I have a sample pdf (attached), and it includes a text object and a rectangle object that have almost the same height. Then I checked the content of the pdf by using itextrup as below:

```
1 1 1 RG
1 1 1 rg
0.12 0 0 0.12 16 50 cm
q
0 0 m
2926 0 l
2926 5759 l
0 5759 l
0 0 l
W
n
Q

1 1 1 RG
1 1 1 rg
q
0 0 m
2926 0 l
2926 5759 l
0 5759 l
0 0 l
W
n
/F1 205.252 Tf
BT
0 0 0 RG
0 0 0 rg
/DeviceGray CS
/OC /oc1 BDC
0 -1 1 0 1648 5330 Tm
0 Tc
100 Tz
(Hello World) Tj
ET
Q
q
0 0 m
2926 0 l
2926 5759 l
0 5759 l
0 0 l
W
n
0 0 0 RG
0 0 0 rg
/DeviceGray CS
6 w
1 j
1 J
1649 5324 m
1649 4277 l
1800 4277 l
1800 5324 l
1649 5324 l
S
EMC
Q
```

Obviously the user space matrix is determined by [0.12 0 0 0.12 16 50], and the height for the rectangle is (1800-1649)*0.12*1=18.12, and for the font size I use 205.252*0.12=24.63024. Since the two values are not close, my problem is how to get the height/size of the font?

[sample.pdf](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=af5d216ec9b3d680)

Comment: You are not looking for the font size here, you are looking for *glyph* sizes – which are notoriously hard to get. The *font* size is independent of the size of the characters it contains.

Comment: The link you have here points to Microsoft's Live OneDrive and something that opens up in an online version of Word. Could you please post the actual PDF file somewhere?

Comment: updated the link for the sample pdf https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=af5d216ec9b3d680

Comment: The glyphs in your text in your PDF do not extend beneath the base line but a certain part of the font size is reserved for glyph parts below that base line. Thus, the box height is considerably smaller than the font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I took a look at your file and you're basically hosed. That's the scientific answer, now let me clarify :)

**Bad PDF!** 
The PDF you have up there as a sample contains a font that is not embedded. That "`/F1 Tf`" command you have there points to the font "ArialMT" in the resources dict for that page. Because the font has not been embedded, you only have two options:

1. Try to find the actual font on the system and extract the necessary information from there.
2. Live with the information in the PDF. Let's start with that.

**Font Descriptor**
Here is an image from pdfToolbox examining the font in the PDF file (caution: I'm associated with this tool):

[image]

I've cut off some of the "`Widths`" table, but other than that this is all of the information you have in the PDF document for this font. And this means you can access the widths for each glyph, but you don't have access to the heights of each glyph. The only information you have regarding heights is the font bounding box which is the union of all glyph bounding boxes. In other words, the font bounding box is guaranteed to be big enough to contain any glyph from the font (both horizontally and vertically).

**System Information**
You don't say *why* you need this information so it becomes a little harder to advise further. But if you can't get the information from the PDF, you're only option is to live with the inaccurate information from the PDF or to turn to the system your code is running on to get you more.

**If** you have the ArialMT font installed, you could basically try to find the font file and then parse the TrueType font file to find the bounding boxes for each glyph. I've done that, it's not funny.

**Or** you can see if your system can't provide you with the information in a better way. Many operating systems / languages have text calls that can get accurate measurements for you. If not, you can brute force it by rendering the text you want in black on a white image and then examining the pixels to see where you hit and thus how big the largest glyph in your text string was.

Wasteful though that last option sounds, it's probably the quickest and easiest to implement and it - depending on your needs - may actually be the best option all around.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a sample pdf (attached), and it includes a text object and a rectangle object that have almost the same height.

Indeed, your PDF is displayed like this:

[image: screen shot]

But looking at this one quickly realizes that the glyphs in your text "Hello World" do not extend beneath the base line like a 'g', 'j' or some other glyphs would:

[image: Some data concerning 'g']

*(The base line is the line through the glyph origins)*

> Since the two values are not close, my problem is how to get the height/size of the font

Obviously the space required for such descenders beneath the base line must also be part of the font size.

Thus, it is completely correct and *not a problem* that the height of the box (18.12) is considerably smaller than the font size (24.63024).

BTW, this corresponds with the specification which describes a font size of 1 to be *arranged so that the nominal height of tightly spaced lines of text is 1 unit*, cf. section 9.2.2 "Basics of Showing Text" of ISO 32000-1. Tightly spaced lines obviously need to include not only glyph parts above the base line but also those below. Additionally it furthermore includes a small gap between such lines as even tightly spaced lines are not expected to touch each other.